# Make map marker direct link onclick for gmaps4rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, gmaps4rails

Currently have the infowindow showing as the 'what happens' when the map marker is clicked, as so:

```
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function(){
            infowindow.open(Gmaps.map.map, marker);
        });
```

How would I get this to work to automatically link to the marker's SHOW page, ie. where is it possible to put in a code reference:

```
<a href='/controller/#{slug}'>#{title}</a>
```

or

```
<%= link_to %> function
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For this kind of needs, I pass a block to the `gmaps4rails` method in the controller ([doc here](https://github.com/apneadiving/Google-Maps-for-Rails/wiki/Controller)):

```
@json = User.all.to_gmaps4rails do |user, marker|
  marker.json "\"id\": #{user.id}"
  # or
  marker.json "\"link\": #{method_to_create_link}"
end
```

This way I can have any additional information I need to create a link or anything.

That said, you could update your listener this way:

```
base_url = "whatever you need";
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function(){
   window.location(base_url + marker.id);
   // or
   window.location(marker.link);
});
```