# Make map marker direct link onclick for gmaps4rails v2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, gmaps4rails2

Instead of showing an infowindow on Gmaps4Rails v.2 I want to go to the url of the object on click.
So, in Gmaps4Rails v.1 it worked like this to add an extra `{link: <path>}` part to the json of each marker and then set the readjust the event listener.

This is quite similar to [Make map marker direct link onclick for gmaps4rails](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8608602/1627888), only here for Gmaps4Rails v.2 (and because it's a complete rewrite I think it's better in a proper question instead of mixing code of the completely different ways of doing this)

I learned that, in order to introduce custom json in Gmaps4Rails v2 I have to

```
  @markers = Gmaps4rails.
              build_markers(objects) do |object, marker|
    marker.lat object.latitude
    marker.lng object.longitude
    marker.json({link: object_path(object)})
  end
```

and to change the event handler I have to add this coffeescript directly after the addMarker call:

```
          markers = handler.addMarkers(#{raw @markers.to_json})

          _.each markers, (marker) ->
            link = < retrieve link from marker somehow?! >
            google.maps.event.clearListeners(marker.getServiceObject(), 'click')
            google.maps.event.addListener marker.getServiceObject(), "click", ->
              window.location = link
            return
```

Unfortunately the link json doesn't seem to be added to the marker, or should be accessed some different way. 
How should it be done?

Answer (score 0):

@markers includes your link. The problem is that addMarkers call the Google constructor in bulk which doesn't use the un-needed parameters, so your link is lost in your JS each loop.

```
# return array of marker objects
addMarkers: (markers_data, provider_options)->
  _.map markers_data, (marker_data)=>
    @addMarker marker_data, provider_options

# return marker object
addMarker: (marker_data, provider_options)->
  marker = @_builder('Marker').build(marker_data, provider_options, @marker_options)
  marker.setMap(@getMap())
  @clusterer.addMarker marker
  marker
```

You have to create individual markers in an ERB each loop, and do something with your link. You can also recreate an Array of markers if that fits better into your code. Here is an example below

```
markers = []

<% @hash.each do |data| %>
  marker = handler.addMarker(<%=raw data.to_json %>)
  markers.push(marker)
  marker.getServiceObject().addListener('click', function() {
    console.log("marker has link <%= data[:link] %>")})
<% end %>

handler.bounds.extendWith(markers);
```